# How to set collation rules with TypeORM for MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, typeorm

I am using `mongoDB` with `TypeORM` to create queries, like this:

```
      const repository = queryRunner.manager.getRepository("...");

      const conditions = { take: ..., skip: ..., where: {...}, order: ... };

      const [entities, count] = await repository.findAndCount(conditions);


      return {
        data: entities as T[],
        count: count
      };
```

This works without any issue. My current task is to implement [localized collation behaviour](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/collation/#behavior). Currently, by default, special characters are not ordered by hungarian rules (A->Á->B->C etc.) and there is an upper-lower character order which I do not want to have (a->A->b->B order).

How can I do that? Here is what I have tried so far:

1. tried setting `ColumnOptions` in [entities](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/entities.md#column-options):

In my base entities, setting `{name: ..., collation: 'hu', charset: 'utf-8'}` did not have any effect.

2. Tried setting collation as a `FindCondition`:

```
      const repository = queryRunner.manager.getRepository("...");

      const conditions = { take: ..., skip: ..., where: {...}, order: ... };

      conditions['collation'] = {
        locale: 'hu',
        caseLevel: false,
        caseFirst: false,
      }

      const [entities, count] = await repository.findAndCount(conditions);


      return {
        data: entities as T[],
        count: count
      };
```

But this has no effect on the query result whatsoever. At this point I am confused, as far as I could tell, both approach should work :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as my research went, it seems not possible after the database is initialized :(

I [should have](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48840147/how-to-view-or-modify-collation-options-set-on-a-mongodb-collection) created different collation options [while defining](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-35314) the collection.

I can add [indexes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/collation/#collation-and-index-use), however. If my queries specify the same collation options, these might work.

**Edit**: this works :)

I must create an index (or indexes if I wish to use multiple) ONCE. For example, in the mongoDB console:

```
db.<tablenamw>.createIndex({hungarianName: 1}, {name: 'hungarianname_hu', collation: {locale:"hu", strength: 2}})
```

Sadly, TypeORM does not support calling collation options directly, in find, findandcount etc. methods, so we must fall back to use NodeJS MongoDB queries:

```
const query = await mongoDbQueryRunnerCollection
            .find(..., {collation: ({locale: "hu", strength: 1})})
            .sort(...)
            .skip(...)
            .limit(...
```

where `mongoDbQueryRunnerCollection` is a direct collection reference object in mongodb nodejs api.